# In which file manager root privilege is available in KUbuntu 18.04.1 LTS?

Tags: kubuntu

I'm using KUbuntu 18.04.1 LTS and there's no root privilege option is available in Dolphin.
So which file manager has root privilege option?
Or if I can have it in Dolphin.

Comment: I added mention of Thunar and PCManFM. Both are nice lightweight file managers which you can run as *root*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Krusader using `sudo apt install krusader`. It's a "Twin-Panel File Manager by KDE" and it's in the repos.

[image: Krusader showing root option]

As far as Dolphin regaining the root feature, you'll probably have to wait until Kubuntu 20.04 if you want an LTS version of Kubuntu.

---

Two simpler graphical file managers with relatively few dependencies are Thunar and PCManFM. You can check out what additional dependencies they will install on *your* system with `apt install -s thunar` or `apt install -s pcmanfm`. The `-s` means you're only running a simulation: that's why there's no need for `sudo`. (Even though a `qt` version of PCManFM is available, I'd avoid that because it brings in far more dependencies.)

Once you've installed either of them, open a terminal and run `sudo -H thunar` or `sudo -H pcmanfm` to open them in **root** mode.

Thunar has a nice cautionary banner whereas PCManFM has a relatively unobtrusive `!`, which I've marked with a red outline, as a caution:

## Thunar as root

[image: Thunar as root]

## PCManFM as root

[image: PCManFM as root]

Comment: I can keep this one alongside Dolphin when root privilege is required.  Thanks a lot.